# How to check which javascript id i am viewing

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, swift

Is it possible to check in Swift 3, if I am in a certain HTML view

if lets say I am in the first view which have an ID "firstView", I would like to call a func

```
let javascript = "document.getElementById('firstView')"
```

or if i am in second view

```
let javascript = "document.getElementById('secondView')"
```

and perform an action depending on which view you are in?

Maybe I dont get how if statements and javascript are working in Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WKWebView the answer then is yes. Here is swift 3.0 version document of the function that you need. Basically you will call this method on your webview object, pass in the javascript checking view ID and then see result from the completion handler.

```
/* @abstract Evaluates the given JavaScript string.
@param javaScriptString The JavaScript string to evaluate.
@param completionHandler A block to invoke when script evaluation completes or fails.
@discussion The completionHandler is passed the result of the script evaluation or an error.
*/
open func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String, completionHandler: ((Any?, Error?) -> Swift.Void)? = nil)
```